# How to create a node and update it on Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, location

I have to store my location in Firebase and keep it updated. I currently can store it, but when location changes it creates a new node, how can I make it to create only one node at the start of my app and update it every time the position changes? Thanks.

Code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = database.getInstance().getReference();
String key = firebaseData.child("Posicion/").push().getKey();
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
childUpdates.put("/Posicion/" + key, latLng);
rootRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

It creates this structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlOQq.png

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: Hi Miguel, welcome! Could you start by including a minimal amount of code that demontrates what you've tried and what you're getting as a result? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please add the code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You are changing node keys between insert and update.

Try to create nodes in the following format, for example:

-locations

-- id (this one must be an unique id you create when app starts or the logged user id)

---- currentLatitude: "xxxxxx"

---- currentLongitude: "yyyyyy"

In this case, the implementation will be something like:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

mDatabase.child("locations").child(user.getUid()).child("currentLatitude").setValue("xxxxxx");
     mDatabase.child("locations").child(user.getUid()).child("currentLongitude").setValue("yyyyyy");
```

Comment: It worked, as you said I wasn't using an unique key for insert, thanks.